# .Net WinForms. How is selection rectangle of ListView controlled programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I was doing an experiment with ListView and faced an issue with its selection rectangle. I created a windows forms application, put 2 ListView controls (listView1, listView2) onto Form1.

I set properties of the controls as below at Design-Time:

listView1: Added 3 items ("Item1", "Item2", "Item3")

listView2: AllowDrop = true.

[image]

I wrote code to drag-drop items from listView1 to listView2 as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView listView = ((ListView)sender);
            ListViewItem listViewItem = listView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
            if (listViewItem != null)
            {
                listView.DoDragDrop(listViewItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }

        private void listView2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }

        private void listView2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView listView = ((ListView)sender);
            ListViewItem listViewItem = ((ListViewItem)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem)));
            listView1.Items.Remove(listViewItem);
            listView.Items.Add(listViewItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am running application and drag-dropping items from listView1 to listView2.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here I am releasing mouse left button. The item from listView1 is successfully getting exported to destination but in listView1 the **selection rectangle is getting drawn**.

[image]

I am not pressing any other key after mouse left button is released, that is all the buttons are in UP-state but the listView1 is happily reacting to mouse move event and changing selection.

[image]
[image]

I couldn't find a way to disable the selection rectangle. I understand that its system doing all this. And it seems to me that there is no way left for .Net developer to be able to do anything about that. So I decided to ask:

**How does a .Net developer control selection rectangle of ListView programmatically?**

Comment: Hello! May be you should disable MultiSelect propery?

Comment: This is being so because you have release MouseUp out of the first ListView and it's still "thinking" that MouseUp have not been yet

Comment: The Capture property is still turned on.  Happened because you used the wrong event to do this, use ListView.ItemDrag instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `MouseDown()`, initiate the drag in `MouseMove()` like this:

```
private void listView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ListView listView = ((ListView)sender);
        ListViewItem listViewItem = listView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
        if (listViewItem != null)
        {
            listView.DoDragDrop(listViewItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @Idle_Mind. Your solution is answering all the requirements in my business logic. It seems that in ListView control mousemove event is where dragging is supposed to be initiated. I will up-vote your answer. But I'd like to know if there is a way to control selection rectangle of ListView on .NET. How does a .Net developer control selection rectangle of ListView programmatically?